# In .NET, Streaming data from SQL to a file

Tags: sql, asynchronous

I have to get a DataTable from SQL, and then convert it to XML (I can't use SQL XML) and save to a file.  The problem is that the file is going to be 5 GB, and I don't have enough memory to download it all and convert it to XML all at once in memory.  I know I should be able to use a DataReader to convert and push the data to the file stream in chunks, but I don't know how to really do this. How can I do the following?

1. Connect to the SQL server asynchronously
2. Call the stored procedure asynchronously
3. Read data from the DataReader asynchronously
4. Convert data from the DataReader to XML and save to file asynchronously

This all has to be asynchronous because it is on a server processing multiple requests and we can't have a thread blocking for each one.

Comment: What type of server processing multiple requests? ASP.NET? Windows Service?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to do anything asynchronously? That may perform better, but will be a lot more complicated.

The simple way of doing it:

- Execute the query to get a DataReader
- Create an XmlWriter writing to the file
- Try to read a row

  - If there are no more rows left, you're done. (Make sure you close the writer/connection etc)
  - If you *do* get a row, write it to the XmlWriter (add an element or whatever you need to do).
- Go back to the previous step.

Comment: I need it to all be asynchronous so that I don't have a thread blocking for each request.  The thread count could get huge and I need to handle a ton of requests.

Answer (score 1):

Is there few large rows (BLOBs), or many many small rows? For large BLOBs, these two articles contain the code needed to handle SQL Server BLOBs in a streaming fashion from C#:

- [Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/)
- [FILESTREAM MVC: Download and Upload images from SQL Server](http://rusanu.com/2011/02/06/filestream-mvc-download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server/)

The first one handles ordinary BLOBs, the second one deals with FILESTREAM BLOBs.

For many small rows you don't need anything fancy, simply open a reader and start streaming into your XmlWriter. The only part which can be asynchronous is the initial query execution, once the results are starting to come back your callback will complete and reading the resulted SqlDataReader is a synchronous operation. This means a thread is blocked for the whole duration of the result read and XML file write, there is simply no ADO.Net API that can avoid this problem. You are right about worrying this can cause probelms (it will) but I have to ask: why is your system doing such large downloads into XML files? Do you want to serialize the result back to an HTTP response?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx)